# get currency value as number

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm currently working in a PDF form that calculates a sum. And the input values are German formatted like:
`1.689,10` or `200` or `0,25`

My problem now is I need to convert these values into numbers, so JavaScript actually can work with them. I tried different methods of replacing them but don't seem to find the right one. This is what I recently tried and somewhat worked till I removed the `,` from the string.

```
var string = getField("inputValue").value;
var string = string.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
var string = getField("inputValue").value;
var string = string.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,(\d{2})$/, '.$1');
var float = parseFloat(string)
```

However this only works if you have 2 degits, If that is flexible, you need to adjust the regex in the second replace call.

So if you had 1 - 2 digits, you'd use

```js
var string = string.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,(\d{1,2})$/, '.$1');
```

Or for an unknown amount

```js
var string = string.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,(\d+)$/, '.$1');
```